# creating numbers in sequence between from and to value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table, call it `sach_temp`, with below sample data.

```
TO_VALUE FROM_VALUE DATE_1

200      100        2/13/2014
238      234        2/13/2014
```

and I want to generate  output like below

> ```
> VALUE   DATE_1
> 100     2/13/2014
> 101     2/13/2014
> 102     2/13/2014
> 103     2/13/2014
> .
> .
> 200     2/13/2014
> 234     2/13/2014
> .
> .
> 238     2/13/2014
> ```

I can think of something like below but it will be working only for single row in table. Can someone guide me how to handle this?

```
   SELECT from_value+rownum-1 value, date_1
     FROM 
    (SELECT     1 JUST_A_COL
          FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT to_value-from_value+1 FROM sach_temp WHERE to_value=200)) a, sach_temp b
  WHERE to_value=200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the maximum difference between two values is 500.  Then you can do this by creating a table with numbers and using `join`.  Here is an example:

```
with nums as (
      select level as lvl from dual
      connect by level < 500
     )
select (st.from_value + n.lvl - 1) as value, st.date_1
from sach_temp st join
     nums n
     on st.from_value + n.lvl - 1<= st.to_value;
```

EDIT:

You don't have to guess at the maximum value.  You can calculate that:

```
with vmax as (
      select max(to_value - from_value + 1) as vmax
      from sach_temp
     ),
     nums as (
      select level as lvl from vmax
      connect by level < vmax.vmax
     )
select (st.from_value + n.lvl - 1) as value, st.date_1
from sach_temp st join
     nums n
     on st.from_value + n.lvl - 1<= st.to_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided your Oracle version is 11g or higher, you can use a recursive with clause and the query is simply:

```
with gen(max_num, min_num, value) as
(
  select max_num, min_num, value from mytable
  union all
  select max_num, min_num + 1, value from gen where min_num < max_num
)
select min_num as num, value 
from gen
order by min_num;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc2c4/3.

Comment: It must actually be "11g Release **2** (aka 11.2) or higher". 11.1 did not support recursive CTEs